# How can I build an app with many activities containing images?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app with 12 activities which contain images.but my app is getting crash after 7th activity.there is no error in code.how can I fix it.please help me.

Comment: Add log cat or the code here so we can get to know what's the error.

Comment: I just create intents and go through the activities with the help of handler

Comment: By doing that the right way, no app can crash. That means there's something which is causing the crash and to know that something, you must add log cat or your code. How can we provide you the solution without knowing the problem?

Comment: Add code and fatal exception....

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sixth);

        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent=new Intent(SixthActivity.this,SeventhActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        },4000);
    }

Comment: paste the exception from logcat to your post

Comment: Thank you every one for coming to my help.I fix it in another way.But can't we have more than 7 activities with different background images

Comment: Yes, you can easily have as many activities you want with as many images but the problem is it affects the performance of your app. Plus you should design an app by obtaining images from the network to reduce the load and to improve performance. Also, 7 is a very small number, many apps already have more than 30-40 activities easily.